# Datatable reorder with columns in Laravel using Yajra

Tags: laravel, datatable

I am working on Laravel Datatables using Yajra .
I am trying to populate the table by passing the array value.

My table structure is as follows:

```
<table id="daily_datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Region</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Country</th>
        <th rowspan="2">No of accounts</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Bank Account Pending</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

My jquery call is as follows:

```
$('#daily_datatable').DataTable({
    processing:true,
    serverSide:true,
    rowReorder: true,
    ajax:
    {
        url:"{!! URL::to('dailyreportDatatable') !!}"
    },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: ['pageLength','csv','excel', 'pdf'],
    columns:[
        {data:'region',name:'region'},
        {data:'country',name:'country'},
        {data:'noofaccounts',name:'noofaccounts'},
        {data:'accountpending',name:'accountpending'},  
    ]
});
```

My controller method is as follows:

```
public function dailydatatable(){
    $final = new Collection;
    $from_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $to_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $pastfrom_date  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-2 days"));
    $pastto_date    = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-2 days"));
    $country = AccMaster::select('ms_region','ms_country','ms_bacc_num')->groupby('ms_country')->get()->toArray();
    foreach($country as $countryCode){
        $pending = AccMaster::select('ms_bacc_num')->where('ms_country',$countryCode['ms_country'])->get()->toArray();
        $bankacc = $this->getBankAcc($pending);

        $final->push([
            'region'=>$countryCode['ms_region'],
            'country'=>$countryCode['ms_country'],
            'noofaccounts'=>$this->getAccounts($countryCode['ms_country']),
            'accountpending'=>$this->getAccPending($countryCode['ms_country'],$bankacc),
        ]);
    }
    return Datatables::of($final)->make(true);
}
```

I am not able to draw the datatable. I get the error

> jquery.dataTables.min.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property
>   '0' of undefined

Comment: What does dd($final); outputs before the return?

Comment: $final = resulted to nothing

Comment: I get the resultant array

Comment: Check if data is returning in console or not?

Answer (score 0):

you need to rewrite your html table because you forget  end `tr` tag

```
<table id="daily_datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Region</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Country</th>
        <th rowspan="2">No of accounts</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Bank Account Pending</th>
    </tr> 
</thead>
```